# R nested for loop structure for all combinations of two variables

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, nested, apply

I want to run a function on each level of a data.frame variable based on the condition of each level of another data.frame variable (or lists, if it's better to work with them for some reason).

If one of the variables achieves a certain condition (e.g., > 15), I then want to run a simple function (e.g., product) on each pair of variables and add the results to a new list. For the sake of my needs and other's future needs, I am hoping for a 
solution that is flexible for any condition and any function.

I am new to programming/R and do not know how to appropriate structure a for loop (or other method) in order to run the function for all combinations of elements in both data.frame variables. It seems like this should be really easy to achieve but I've been searching for hours and cannot find a solution.

This is the nested for loop code I am working on:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(c(10, 20, 30))

list1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(df1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(df2)) {
    if (df2[j,] > 15) {
      list1[[i]] <-  df1[i,] * df2[j,]}
    }}
list1
```

When I run the current code I get and empty list results: list().
What I want returned is something like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 20

[[2]]
[1] 30

[[3]]
[1] 40

[[4]]
[1] 60

[[5]]
[1] 60

[[6]]
[1] 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, here are two of them: one is your `for` loop and another is vectorised.

**`for` loop**

There are few mistakes in your code, both `df1` and `df2` have `length`= 1.  Therefore, `i` and `j` are only set as 1. This can be fixed by using `nrow` instead of `length`. Another thing is to create an `index` outside the loop to assign your results to list.  Following code works

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(c(10, 20, 30))

list1 <- list()
index=0
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    if (df2[j,] > 15) {
      index=index+1
      list1[[index]] <-  df1[i,] * df2[j,]}
  }}
list1

[[1]]
[1] 20

[[2]]
[1] 30

[[3]]
[1] 40

[[4]]
[1] 60

[[5]]
[1] 60

[[6]]
[1] 90
```

**vectorized way**

Using `expand.grid` to generate the required combinations and `prod` to find their products

```
dat=expand.grid(df1[,1], df2[df2 > 15,1])
dat=dat[order(dat$Var1),]
apply(dat, 1, prod)

 1  4  2  5  3  6 
20 30 40 60 60 90
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `sapply` with two inputs to iterate across `nrow` of both data frames with list conversion:

```
mat <- sapply(1:nrow(df2), function(i, j) ifelse(df2[j,] > 15, df1[i,]*df2[j,], NA),
              1:nrow(df1))

mat <- mat[!is.na(mat)]
mat
# [1] 20 30 40 60 60 90

as.list(mat)    
# [[1]]
# [1] 20
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 30
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 40
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 60
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 60
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 90
```

Comment: Great (and faster?) alternative to @nsinghs answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: One question: why do you use sapply and not lapply?

Comment: `lapply` does not take two vector inputs. Note: apply family avoids bookkeeping required of `for` loops and this solution uses a vectorized `ifelse`.